# Wipe everything after failed decryption attempts, but make it usable?

Tags: security, encryption

I have CM10 running on my rooted Galaxy Nexus and I just enabled the disk encryption. However, I can't find any options what happens after a few failed attempts? I would like to reset and wipe my data and files so that it **will be usable, but without any of my data**. Cerberus is flashed, so I think I'll have a better chance at recovering my phone if it's usable and not completely locked.

I have set a profile with tasker + secure settings to shutdown after 3 failed PIN attempts ([which is different than the encryption password](http://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2012/08/changing-androids-disk-encryption.html)), so I should be save there and a thief would be forced to guess my much safer encryption password.

I know that I can do it with cerberus, but only manually.

@Robert answered [a similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13720/can-android-phones-be-set-to-automatically-wipe-all-data-after-a-certain-amount/13735#13735), that is possible with encryption, but doesn't get specific.

Bonus point: Is there any possibility to use a pattern instead of a PIN for the display lock? It's unavailable after encrypting..

Comment: Define 'usable'? Android will automatically wipe after 30  unsuccessful attempts, but this value is hard coded.