# Lock screen security - reboot after X invalid PINs

Tags: security, lock-screens

I used [following methodology](http://nelenkov.blogspot.be/2012/08/changing-androids-disk-encryption.html) to create a strong boot password on the phone, at the same time keeping a weaker PIN for screen unlock. Now I want to make sure that if someone tries to pick up a PIN, that the phone reboots, which would make it fallback to a more secure password prompt.

The default setting is to put a 30-second delay after 5 invalid attempts. I wonder if I can tweak these settings in any way to lower 5 to smaller number, and replace cooldown with a reboot.

If stock Android does not offer that experience, maybe there is a 3rd party application?

Comment: related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13720/can-android-phones-be-set-to-automatically-wipe-all-data-after-a-certain-amount

Answer (score 1):

Stock ROM doesn't. Apart from building custom ROM or installing DPM, there are 3rd-party apps, [SnooperStopper](https://f-droid.org/packages/cz.eutopia.snooperstopper/) & [Wrong PIN Shutdown](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.nuntius35.wrongpinshutdown/).

*SnooperStopper* will power off device what option can not be changed. However, custom command can be issued in *Wrong PIN Shutdown*.